# Â appearing before £ in csv where encoding is set to UTF8

Tags: asp.net, csv, encoding

I am trying to download a csv file from a memory stream and while it is mostly working ok I noticed that all of the £ characters are appearing as Â£

I have looked around online and seen several people saying to set the contentEncoding to UTF8 (among several others) but this seemed to have no effect at all

here is my code

```
byte[] attachment = MS.ToArray();

         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Wfielname.csv");
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", attachment.Length.ToString());
         Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.ms-csv";
         Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
         Response.BinaryWrite(attachment);
         Response.Flush();
         Response.Close();
```

I have also tried `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` / `System.Text.Encoding.UTF7`/ `System.Text.Encoding.UTF32`/ `System.Text.Encoding.Default` and `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

which did not solve the problem. does anyone have any ideas that may help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes seen this problem when the source file has previously been interpreted with the wrong character encoding (e.g. iso-8859-1) and then saved as UTF 8.  Store your source stream as a binary file, and open it in a hex editor (e.g. xvi32) and check what byte sequence you have for your £ symbols.

Comment: I am not really sure if I am doing the right thing but the Â was C2 and the £ was A3. does this help?

Comment: That's definitely the correct encoding for UTF8, so I have no idea why it didn't work when you set this as your content encoding above.  Sorry I can't help further.